# Envío de variable por método $_GET

Tags: php, get

Tengo tres páginas en PHP:

- Mapa.php
- Ficha.php
- Panel.php

En la primera página envío el valor de una variable a la página Ficha.php con el metodo `$_GET` de la siguiente manera:

Mapa.php:

```
<a href="/plataforma/ficha.php?var=">
```

En Ficha.php la recibo así:

```
<?php
    $variable = $_GET['var'];
?> 

//Así la imprimo y me imprime el valor que estoy enviando

<p>Folio: <b><?php echo $variable; ?></b></p>
```

De igual forma necesito enviar esa variable a la página Panel.php y 
lo hago de la misma forma:

```
 <a href="/plataforma/panel.php?var=">
```

y la recibo nuevamente de la misma forma:

```
$variable = $_GET['var'];
```

pero cuando la imprimo no imprime nada y se queda vacío. No se a qué se deba, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Si entiendo sus respuestas, pero lo que necesito es llevarme el valor que desde primera instancia estoy cachando (almacenado en $variable) y enviar ese valor a mi otra página, lo que no sé es donde usted dice

 formulario.php?var="Alfredo"

Como sustituyo ese "Alfredo" por el valor que lleva $variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné por si a alguien le ocurría lo mismo y le sirve,

este tema se centra en **Pasar variables ya definidas**, para pasar los valores o datos que almacena una variable a otra página se puede lograr a través de una enlace como lo estaba intentando, pero cuando se necesita pasar un valor que ya esta almacenado en nuestra variable haremos lo siguiente

```
<?php 
echo "<a href='destino,php?var=$variable'>Ir al enlace</a>";
?>
```

Fuente:
[Traspasar datos](http://aprende-web.net/php/php4_2.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Tienes:**

Mapa.php:

```
<a href="/plataforma/ficha.php?var=ValorVariable"></a>
```

Le asigno "ValorVariable" como ejemplo.

En Ficha.php

En Ficha.php la recibo así:

```
<?php
$variable = $_GET['var'];
?> 

<p>Folio: <b><?php echo $variable; ?></b></p>
```

**Así lo imprimes y todo ok!...comprendo**

Según veo cuando pasas a **Panel.php** te hace falta enviar de nuevo la variable que acabas de recibir:

```
<a href="/plataforma/panel.php?var=<?php echo $variable; ?>"></a>
```

De esta forma lo recibes en Panel.php y lo puedes imprimir.

```
$variable = $_GET['var'];
echo $variable;
```

Comment: Me fue útil tu solución también, mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para que var obtenga un valor debe tener algún valor al final de la cadena ejempo:

//FICHERO ORIGEN

```
<a href="/plataforma/ficha.php?var=hola">
```

//FICHERO DESTINO

```
$variable = $_GET['var'];
```

// $variable tendría el valor 'hola'

Si obtienes un valor en ficha.php estará guardado en caché pero no es un valor que le pases por el enlace. Espero que puedas entender esto, si necesitas más información sobre pasar valores por url get puedes [consultarlo aquí](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/317.php)

Espero que esto te ayude un saludo